# Derivative of integral with respect of the integrand

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am reading an article about international economics and the authors define the budget constraint as the inner product:
$$\int_0^1 p(z)x(z)dz=I$$
The Sum of prices times quantities over a continuum of goods is equal to I (no savings). Then when they derive this expression with respect to $x(z)$ the result is:
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial x(z)}=p(z)$$
while I understand that this must be the case, specially interpolating from the discrete case, I don't understand mathematically how can it be possible.

Then, could someone provide proof of why this is true?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int_{0}^{1} p(z)x(z)\,dz$ is not a function, it's a number. So, if you differentiate both sides of equality
$$\int_{0}^{1} p(z)x(z)\,dz = I$$
then you'll get the equality (if first equality is correct then I is also a number)
$$0 = 0$$
But if you differentiate (by z) both sides of equality
$$\int p(z)x(z)\,dz = I$$
then you'll get the equality
$$p(z)x(z) = \frac{dI}{dz}$$
and then (assuming $x(z)\neq 0$)
$$p(z) = \frac{dI}{x(z)dz} \neq \frac{dI}{dx(z)}$$
unless $x(z)=Ce^z$, in which case indeed $dx(z) = x'(z)dz = Ce^z dz= x(z)dz$.

So there is a typo or some information is missing.